# How can I load tf js model?

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to load tf js model (convert from keras h5) but model is not opened

I tried to train keras model and convert it to tfjs and use it

my Keras model is as follows

```
pre_model = keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=[224, 224, 3], weigths="imagenet")
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(106,), dtype=tf.float32)
feat = pre_model(input1)
#fully connected layers
#x1 is tensor of input1, x2 is tensor of input2
x = keras.layers.concatenate([x1, x2])
#fully connected layers
output = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[output])
```

I served the model.json file using json-server and just load the tfjs model, but I get this error

```
async function loadmodel() {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://localhost:4000/file');
}
loadmodel()
```

Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: i don't know it will help or not but if you want to just convert js to py you can use [js2py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadModel uses fetch under the hood. And fetch cannot access the local files directly. It is meant to be used to get files served by a server. More on this here. To load a local file with the browser, there is two approaches, asking the user to upload the file with Or serving the file by a server.

Comment: Should I host it on the server instead of local hosting?